# Check if user accepted that the app know his location

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I want to know if user accepted the app to check his location. Is it true that if "location = nil" the user not authorized?

```
coreLocationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[coreLocationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[coreLocationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
location = [coreLocationManager location];
[coreLocationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

Comment: Have you tried searching Apple's documentation and/or trying it yourself to find out?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to know if a user authorized your application for checking his location, you have to use

```
+(CLAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatus;
```

This class method returns a `CLAuthorizationStatus` constant which can assume these values;

```
typedef enum {
   kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined = 0,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied,
   kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized
} CLAuthorizationStatus;
```

Finally, to check if your app is authorized, you can simply do:

```
if ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
{
    // Your app is authorized!
}
```

Hope this can helps and you can find more info in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/CLAuthorizationStatus).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `authorizationStatus` method for doing this.

You can use:

```
if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] && 
   [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus] == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized)
{
  // Do your code
}
```

`locationServicesEnabled` for checking  whether location services are enabled on the device.

Reference [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/CLLocationManager/authorizationStatus)

> `authorizationStatus`
>
> Returns the application’s authorization status for using location
>   services.
>   `+ (CLAuthorizationStatus)authorizationStatus`
>
> **Return Value**
>
> A value indicating whether the application is authorized to use
>   location services. Discussion
>
> The authorization status of a given application is managed by the
>   system and determined by several factors. Applications must be
>   explicitly authorized to use location services by the user and
>   location services must themselves currently be enabled for the system.
>   A request for user authorization is displayed automatically when your
>   application first attempts to use location services. Availability
>
> ```
> Available in iOS 4.2 and later.
> ```
>
> Declared In CLLocationManager.h